# What is Liebermann nitroso test?

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines

From the articles in the internet , I found that there are two reactions which are being called Lieberman nitroso test .

One is the test of 2 degree amine in which a 2 degree amine is converted to N - nitroso amine using nitrous acid  . And this product reacts with phenol to form a red solution which turn blue on addition of alkali . Confirming the presence of 2 degree amine .

And another is the direct reaction of phenol with nitrous acid to form Indo-phenol giving same characteristic red and blue colour .

I am confused and have tried to refer to a lot of sources but with no success .

Comment: Yes, it is a test for both phenol and secondary amines. See: https://www.scribd.com/document/369333943/Liebermann-Nitroso-Test-and-Ninhydrin-Test