# Diazotisation of aniline derivatives

Tags: organic-chemistry

I want to know if **N-methyl aniline** $(\ce{PhNHCH3})$ can undergo *diazotisation* under suitable conditions and in the presence of $\ce{NaNO2}/\ce{HCl}.$

The mechanism involves loss of two $\ce{H+}$ during the formation of the diazo compound, but if we have one $\ce{CH3}$ and one $\ce{H}$ instead of two $\ce{H}$ (as we have for aniline), will the $\ce{CH3+}$ act as a good leaving group? Is diazotisation of $\ce{PhNHCH3}$ feasible?

Comment: $\ce{PhNHCH3}$ is *N*-methylaniline, not *N*-methylphenylaniline (which is $\ce{Ph2NCH3}$). Check the names/formulas and fix them accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Secondary amines react with nitrous acid to give N-nitroso compounds [reference here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Amines/Reactivity_of_Amines/Reaction_of_Amines_with_Nitrous_Acid)

N-Methylaniline will give N-Methyl-N-nitrosoaniline as shown below
[image]

Comment: Which further gives Liebermann nitroso reaction...

Comment: Indeed  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/118764/what-is-liebermann-nitroso-test